# Efficient random code generator

Tags: c#, beginner, random

I made a 16 character code generator. It works like a charm now, but I was wondering if there's any way to do it more efficiently.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    //Globals
    string[] Letters = new string[27] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    string[] Numbers = new string[9] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

    Random r = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    int a = 0;

    private string[] generateCode()
    {

        string[] RL = new string[9];
        string[] RN = new string[9];

        //Random letters
        while (i < 9)
        {
            RL[i] = Letters[r.Next(0, Letters.Length - 1)];
            i++;
        }
        //Random numbers
        while (a < 9)
        {
            RN[a] = Numbers[r.Next(0, Numbers.Length - 1)];
            a++;
        }

        TextBox.Text = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}-{4}{5}{6}{7}-{8}{9}{10}{11}-{12}{13}{14}{15}", RN[0], RL[1], RN[1], RL[2], RN[2], RL[3], RN[3], RL[4], RN[4], RL[5], RN[5], RL[6], RN[6], RL[7], RN[7], RL[8], RN[8]);

        //Resetting the while loop
        i = 0;
        a = 0;

        //Clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(TextBox.Text);
        Message.Content = ("Copied to clipboard!");

        return RL;
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        generateCode();
    }
```

Comment: If you are not looking for specific order of characters and digits you can try Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Take(16).

Comment: @rajasekharareddy To be fair I have no idea how to make use of that, an example would be nice. But I will google it eitherway

Comment: @5parc [Guid.NewGuid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you 36 letter random unique value. You can take 16 characters from it.

Comment: @rajasekharareddy I asked for an example buddy, but thanks for your input eitherway.

Comment: @rajasekharareddy A guid does not give random values. Unique, yes, but not random per se.

Comment: 27 capital English letters.. very nice ;)

Comment: @Blorgbeard I was thinking of a way that makes the string format part much smaller, I didn't necessarily want the random code to be number-letter-number-letter, but half letters & half numbers. Thanks for your feedback tho!

Comment: @austinwernli I got two "H"s on accident, just noticed that now

Comment: Also you are not using `RL[0]`. and if you do then you will have 18 parameters in your string.Format. not 16. two of them remain useless. so you can remove them.

Comment: there are two things more. Why you return `string[] RL`. do you need it later? i dont see any use of it here. Also you can define counters `i` and `a` as a local variable. Accessing local variables is faster than global variables. then you dont have to reset the counters too since its value set to 0 each time you use the method.

Comment: My code won't run without returning RL, I don't know how to solve this problem. And I am used to just return values in methods which isn't a best practice. But good idea to make I & A local variable

Comment: did you make your method void when you removed the return? also use char array in answer given. but not stringbuilder. its not faster and its even slower.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary No I didn't, I will do that! So "private void string [] generateCode ()" instead of  of "private string [] generateCode ()" right?

Comment: @5parc, you would do `private void GenerateCode()` C# standard is capitalized method names by the way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` and `a` shouldn't be class members, they should be declared in your method scope. That is because they are specifically used for your method implementation. This way, you won't need to reset them afterwards. Some people already pointed out that you should use the C# code conventions (`generateCode` should be `GenerateCode`).

You don't need to use `while` loops in this case. You want to do an operation X times, and the `for` is all designed for this. Also, there is no need for the 2 loops, only one could do the job.

`RN` and `RL` are quite confusing variable names, I understand that they are in fact `randomNumbers` and `randomLetters`, I think these names are clearer!

We see the int `9` used alot in the code, what if I wanted to change it to... `12`. I'd have to check all the code and change all the instances of `9` for `12`. This looks like a good scenario to use a constant!

Your method `GenerateCode` should have one simple responsability, to generate a code. So, this method shouldn't worry about the `TextBox` nor the `ClipBoard`. This method should return the generated code, and your `Generate_Click` method should take care of the rest.

It is a good practice, if I recall, to use a `static Random` variable, in order to have a better... randomability (I just invented that).

I'm not sure if this is a best practice or a personnal preference, but I like to see the `private` visibility modifier indicated, even if by default it is `private`. This way I can make sure it is intended to be private and that the developer didn't simply forget it.

So right now, this is what the code looks like :

```
private const int NumberOfLettersOrNumbers = 9;

private string[] letters = new string[27] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
private string[] numbers = new string[9] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };

private static Random r = new Random();

private static string GenerateCode()
{
    string[] randomLetters = new string[NumberOfLettersOrNumbers];
    string[] randomNumbers = new string[NumberOfLettersOrNumbers];

    for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfLettersOrNumbers; i++)
    {
        randomLetters[i] = letters[r.Next(0, letters.Length - 1)];
        randomNumbers[i] = numbers[r.Next(0, numbers.Length - 1)];
    }

    return String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}-{4}{5}{6}{7}-{8}{9}{10}{11}-{12}{13}{14}{15}", randomNumbers[0], randomLetters[1], randomNumbers[1], randomLetters[2], randomNumbers[2], randomLetters[3], randomNumbers[3], randomLetters[4], randomNumbers[4], randomLetters[5], randomNumbers[5], randomLetters[6], randomNumbers[6], randomLetters[7], randomNumbers[7], randomLetters[8], randomNumbers[8]);
}

private void Generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string generatedCode = generateCode();
    TextBox.Text = generatedCode;

    //Clipboard
    Clipboard.SetText(generatedCode);
    Message.Content = ("Copied to clipboard!");
}
```

Now, if we want to get rid of the `String.Format` that is a little difficult to read, *and* keep the fact that you alternate between a number and a letter in your code, we will try and use a `StringBuilder` instead of 2 `string[]`

```
private const int CodeSize = 16;
private const int GroupSize = 4;
private const string GroupSeparator = "-";

private static string GenerateCode()
{
    StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();

    while(code.Length < CodeSize)
    {
        code.Append(letters[r.Next(0, letters.Length - 1)]);
        code.Append(numbers[r.Next(0, numbers.Length - 1)]);
    }

    //Note the "+1" at the end of the loop, because we want to separate after the 4th character, so the 4th index, not the 3rd.
    for(int separatorIndex = GroupSize; separatorIndex < code.Length; separatorIndex += GroupSize + 1)
    {
        code.Insert(separatorIndex, GroupSeparator);
    }

    return code.ToString();
}
```

The code right above constructs your code in 2 times, the first where we will add one number and one letter one after another until we reach our `CodeSize`. The second part will have the responsibility to add your separators. The real advantage is that you don't need to worry anymore about your array's indexes, which could become confusing.

Now, if we want to remove the second loop, we need to be able to tell when to `Append` the `GroupSeparator` at the good moment in the first `while`. To do so, we need to be able to tell how long will the final code, including the separators, will be. Let's introduce another constant to do the maths!

```
private const int SizeWithSeparator = CodeSize + (CodeSize - 1) / GroupSize;
```

Since we don't want a separator at the end of the code, we need to do `codeSize - 1`, and we need to see how many separators will be neccessary, hence the `CodeSize / GroupSize`.

```
private const int CodeSize = 16;
private const int GroupSize = 4;
private const int SizeWithSeparator = CodeSize + (CodeSize - 1) / GroupSize;
private const string GroupSeparator = "-";

private string GenerateCode()
{
    var code = new StringBuilder();
    int separatorIndex = 0;

    while(code.Length < SizeWithSeparator)
    {
        //We need the second section of the condition to not have a separator at index 0.
        if(separatorIndex % GroupSize == 0 && separatorIndex != 0)
        {
            code.Append(GroupSeparator);
        }

        code.Append(letters[r.Next(0, letters.Length - 1)]);
        code.Append(numbers[r.Next(0, numbers.Length - 1)]);

        //We just added 2 characters to our code.
        separatorIndex += 2;
    }

    return code.ToString();
}
```

We need to check the condition before incrementing the `separatorIndex` in order not to have a separator at the end of the code. Also, note that I used the `var` keyword as @Abbas proposed, it is a great keyword to use when it is easy to guess what is the type!

This last step might not be a good idea, but I decided I was gonna share it with you anyway. You do not need the 2 arrays, thanks to the ASCII table. As you might know, `'A' = 65`.  Now, as I wrote before, using hardcoded values in the code isn't good, and I'm pretty sure you don't want to introduce constants like :

```
const AAscii = 65; 
const ZAscii = 90;
```

So we will extract this logic in a method, in order to hide to your method these ugly hardcoded values.

```
private char GetRandomLetter()
{
    //65 == "A"
    //91 == "Z" + 1
    return (char)r.Next(65,91);
}
```

So it would look like this :

```
private const int CodeSize = 16;
private const int GroupSize = 4;
private const int SizeWithSeparator = CodeSize + (CodeSize - 1) / GroupSize;
private const string GroupSeparator = "-";

private static Random r = new Random();

private char GetRandomLetter()
{
    //65 == "A"
    //91 == "Z" + 1
    return (char)r.Next(65,91);
}

private string GenerateCode()
{
    var code = new StringBuilder();
    int separatorIndex = 0;

    while(code.Length < SizeWithSeparator)
    {
        //We need the second section of the condition to not have a separator at index 0.
        if(separatorIndex % GroupSize == 0 && separatorIndex != 0)
        {
            code.Append(GroupSeparator);
        }

        code.Append(GetRandomLetter());
        code.Append(r.Next(1,10).ToString());

        //We just added 2 characters to our code.
        separatorIndex += 2;
    }

    return code.ToString();
}
```

But wait, there's more! At the moment, we have constant values that define our code rules. 16 characters, groups of 4 and a "-" separator. These values could (should?) be parameters to an object!

So let's introduce the `CodeGenerator` class, with a static method, `Generate`.

```
public class CodeGenerator
{
    private static Random r = new Random();

    private static char GetRandomLetter()
    {
        //65 == "A"
        //91 == "Z" + 1
        return (char)r.Next(65,91);
    }

    public static string Generate(int characterCount, int groupSize, string separator = "-")
    {
        int sizeWithSeparator = characterCount + (characterCount - 1) / groupSize;
        var code = new StringBuilder();
        var separatorIndex = 0;

        while(code.Length < sizeWithSeparator)
        {
            //We need the second section of the condition to not have a separator at index 0.
            if(separatorIndex % groupSize == 0 && separatorIndex != 0)
            {
                code.Append(separator);
            }

            code.Append(GetRandomLetter());
            code.Append(r.Next(1,10).ToString());

            //We just added 2 characters to our code.
            separatorIndex += 2;
        }

        return code.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now, you can reuse this code generator for other codes. The `separator` is an optional parameter. I don't know if you already know about this, but if not, here's the link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264739(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 7):

First a bit of nitpicking:

**Naming conventions:**

Please read the [**Capitalization Conventions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) by Microsoft. Method names will always be capitalized:

- `generateCode()` becomes `GenerateCode()`

Your private fields (globals in your code) should be lower case: `letters` and `numbers`.

**The `var` keyword:**

From the [**C# Programming Guide**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx):

> The var keyword can also be useful when the specific type of the variable is tedious to type on the keyboard, or is obvious, or does not add to the readability of the code.

So lines like:

```
string[] RL = new string[9];
```

would become:

```
var RL = new string[9];
```

---

**Separation of concerns:**

From the method that generates the code, you set the value of the textbox. This is not a good practice reagarding maintenance of your code. What if you want to use that method somewhere else?

Assign the value of the method to a variable in the click event of the button and assign that value to the textbox.

```
private string GenerateCode()
{
    //...
}

private void Generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var code = GenerateCode();
    YourTextBox.Text = code;
}
```

And is there a specific reason why your code returns the `RL` array?

---

The initialisation of your arrays could also be made simpler:

```
private readonly char[] letters= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
private readonly char[] numbers = "01234567489".ToCharArray();
```

The answer of [**austin wernli**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/74847/austin-wernli) already provides a nice solution, I have written another way of achieving this. This method uses only one loop and no if statements:

```
private readonly char[] _letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
private readonly char[] _numbers = "01234567489".ToCharArray();
private readonly Random _random = new Random();

private string GenerateCode()
{
    var parts = new string[4];

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        parts[i] = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", _numbers[_random.Next(0, _numbers.Length)], _letters[_random.Next(0, _letters.Length)], _numbers[_random.Next(0, _numbers.Length)], _letters[_random.Next(0, _letters.Length)]);
    }

    return String.Join("-", parts);
}
```

Example usage:

```
private void Generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    YourTextBox.Text = GenerateCode();
}
```

This can be a bit simplified by generating an extension method to get a random element from the array:

- The extension method:

  ```
  public static class Extensions
  {
      private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

      public static char GetRandom(this char[] collection)
      {
          return collection[Random.Next(0, collection.Length)];
      }
  }
  ```
- The method:

  ```
  private string GenerateCode()
  {
      var parts = new string[4];

      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      {
          parts[i] = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}", _numbers.GetRandom(), _letters.GetRandom(), _numbers.GetRandom(), _letters.GetRandom());
      }

      return String.Join("-", parts);
  }
  ```

Comment: Nice review, not just suggestion for efficiency improvement. Though not mentioned, you took care of those class member loop counters. a and i did not need to be scoped at class.

Comment: @Andy Wiesendanger Using this implementation indees 'solves' the faulty use of class members, thanks for mentioning. I didn't mention it because I forgot about them as I didn't need them anymore. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could shorten up some pieces of your code and use loops to generate your code instead of `string.Format`

To make the loops more efficient, you can use a `StringBuilder` So that you do not need to create a new string every time with string concatenation.

You can also shorten up your initial `Number` and `Letter` declarations using `string.ToCharArray`

Also, I didn't see anywhere you were using the `return RL;` in the code you have provided.

This code is not tested by the way, so there may be some bugs in it.

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window {

    char[] Letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();
    char[] Numbers = "123456789".ToCharArray();

    Random r = new Random();

    private void generateCode() {

        var codeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var codeLength = 16;
        for (var i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                codeBuilder.Append(Numbers[r.Next(0, Numbers.Length - 1]));
                codeBuilder.Append(Letters[r.Next(0, Letters.Length - 1]));
                codeBuilder.Append(Numbers[r.Next(0, Numbers.Length - 1]));
                codeBuilder.Append(Letters[r.Next(0, Letters.Length - 1]));
            }
            if (i < codeLength - 1) {
                codeBuilder.Append("-");
            }
        }

        var codeString = codeBuilder.ToString();

        TextBox.Text = codeString;
        Clipboard.SetText(codeString);

        Message.Content = ("Copied to clipboard!");
    }

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Generate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        generateCode();
    }
```

Comment: +1 for char array. But not that StringBuilder is not efficient here. Because it takes more time to create StringBuilder than finishing this little task. StringBuilder is not for generating 1 line string. its for about more than 50 line and up to thousands of lines.

Comment: I have grown into the habit of using `StringBuilder` in my loops, as the requirements can expand, and the `StringBuilder` will just become much more efficient. Plus I think it makes it a little more readable as to what you are trying to accomplish (Building a string of course) heh. But, I do agree that this example it may not be worth it.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I like `Jon Skeets` answer and comments on this post about `StringBuilder` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133185/stringbuilder-versus-string-concat